# How do I solve this IndexError inside a for Loop?

Tags: python, function, for-loop, pyautogui, index-error

I have been playing around with Python for over a year now and written several automation codes which I use on a daily basis. I have been writing this auto typer for Python, here is the code:

```
import pyautogui as pt
from time import sleep

empty_file = "C:\\Users\\Lucas\\Desktop\\PycharmProjects\\Automate\\main\\screenshots\\empty_file.png"
text_write = "C:\\Users\\Lucas\\Desktop\\PycharmProjects\\Automate\\main\\text_write.txt"

with open(text_write, 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()
    sentence = text.split("\n")

position0 = pt.locateOnScreen(empty_file, confidence=.8)
x = position0[0]
y = position0[1]
pt.moveTo(x, y, duration=.05)
pt.leftClick()

def post_text():
    pt.moveTo(x-370, y+95, duration=.1)
    for lines in range(len(text)):
        pt.typewrite(str(sentence[lines],) + "\n", interval=.01)
        with pt.hold('shift'):
            pt.press('tab', presses=5)
        sleep(2)


post_text()
```

The code completely works but at the end instead of the code breaking it gives me this error:

```
C:\Users\Lucas\PycharmProjects\wechat_bot\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Lucas/Desktop/PycharmProjects/Automate/main/auto_typer.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lucas\Desktop\PycharmProjects\Automate\main\auto_typer.py", line 26, in <module>
    post_text()
  File "C:\Users\Lucas\Desktop\PycharmProjects\Automate\main\auto_typer.py", line 20, in post_text
    pt.typewrite(str(sentence[lines],) + "\n", interval=.01)
IndexError: list index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I suspect the issue has to do specifically with the line:

```
str(sentence[lines],
```

I haven't found a solution yet. Am I supposed to be using len() or would and if else statement be better?

Comment: You are using `text` to determine the index `lines`, but then use that index for `sentence`. This seems really strange to me. Usually the index is calculated from the length of the list you want to use it on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are doing

```
    for lines in range(len(text)):
```

but then you later do

```
sentence[lines]
```

This will only work `text` is shorter than or the same length as `sentence`. But there is no such guarantee in your code.

Instead, you should do

```
    for lines in range(len(sentence)):
```

Or better yet loop over the lines without indexes:

```
for line in sentence:
```

And then you can just do `line` instead of `sentence[lines]`.

Comment: Thank you, this solution worked for me, and the second alternative [for line in sentence:] makes it look very clean. I appreciate it.

Comment: @LucasPotjer This is the standard way to loop over a list in Python. We don't dor `for i in range(n)` unless we absolutely need indexes. And even then we prefer `enumerate()` whenever possible.